How to remove the reconfigure button from android (glance) widget
I want to have a glance widget that can be resized, but doesn't provide any additional configuration, and thus I don't want this "Reconfigure button".

If I remove android:widgetFeatures="reconfigurable|configuration_optional" from its .xml, whenever I add an instance of it I get:
Error in Glance App Widget
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No app widget info for 43
  at androidx.glance.appwidget.AppWidgetSession.processEmittableTree(AppWidgetSession.kt:169)
  at androidx.glance.appwidget.AppWidgetSession$processEmittableTree$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:15)
  at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:104)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)

